# Looping through all RGB combinations within a limit

Tags: java, for-loop, colors, combinations, rgb

I am using the following code currently to loop through pixels in an image and return the coordinates of the pixel with RGB values the same as defined in the if statement:

```
outerloop:
        for (int y = 0; y < image.getHeight(); y = y + 1) {
            for (int x = 0; x < image.getWidth(); x = x + 1) {
                Color mycolor = new Color(image.getRGB(x, y));
                int red = mycolor.getRed();
                int green = mycolor.getGreen();
                int blue = mycolor.getBlue();               

                if (red == 183 & green == 86 & blue == 182){
                    System.out.println(x,y);                    
                    break outerloop;
                }
            }
        }
```

The problem now is that the RGB values vary very slightly every time in the application so I am trying to add a sort of "tolerance" to the currently constant RGB values. For example, in one case Red could be 185, green could be 89 and blue for example could be the same (182).

I understand I could just define all the conditions using the OR (||) function within the if statement but as this would require a lot of code is there any simpler solution? For example defining a positive tolerance as a constant and looping through all combinations of the RGB values within this tolerance?

Comment: `if (Math.abs(red - 183) < tolerance && Math.abs(green - 86) < tolerance && ...` etc?

Comment: Would it make more sense to convert to HSV? Saturation would be roughly the same, or at least could probably be ignored. I guess conversion would be slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be very slow to loop through all permutations of the colors within tolerance: let's say that you have a tolerance of `+/- 5`, that would require checking 1331 different colors (`11 reds * 11 greens * 11 blues`).

It is much faster just to change your condition `red == 183` to something like `Math.abs(red - 183) < tolerance` or `(red >= 183 - tolerance || red <= 183 + tolerance)` (similarly for other channels).

Answer (score 0):

Rather than check that your values are explicitly equal to a list of numbers, you'll be happier to check that they are within a certain range. You could do this with something like `(180<x & x<185)`, but it's a little cleaner to use absolute value:

```
int TOLERANCE = 3;
boolean in_range(int value, int setpt) {
    return abs(value-setpt) <= TOLERANCE;
}
```

And then in your loop, your conditional would look like:

```
int R_SETPT = 183;
int G_SETPT = 86;
int B_SETPT = 182;

if (in_range(red, R_SETPT) &
    in_range(green, G_SETPT) &
    in_range(blue, B_SETPT)) {
    // etc.
```